# Problem when using keyboard commands in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

While doing some game programming, I ran into a problem with the keyboard commands. In my code, I have a food bar and a money bank variable named `money_bar`. The food bar in my game would increase when I press a key, say <kbd>f</kbd>, in my game, and also the game deduct say $10 from my money_bar when I press <kbd>f</kbd>.
The food bar shows the current amount of food I have, which is supposed to decrease every second. However, it appears that none of my keyboard commands in the `event()` are working. May I know what is the problem in my code?
This is my `food_bar` and `money_bar  initialisation:

```
def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.living = 1
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        pygame.display.set_caption(TITLE)
        self.time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        pygame.key.set_repeat(500, 100)
        self.all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.console = Console(self, 0)
        self.player = Player(self, 390, 595)
        self.work = Work(self, 450, 250)
        self.food_station = Food_Station(self, 750, 200)
        self.food = Food(self, 25, 20)
        self.education = Education(self, 300, 10)
        self.school = School(self, 100, 200)
        self.family = Family(self, 600, 10)
        self.money = Money(self, 800, 15)
        initial_food = 100
        self.food_bar = initial_food
        initial_money = 0
        self.money_bar = initial_money
        initial_education = "Student"
        self.education_level = initial_education
        initial_family = 3
        self.family_member = 3
```

This is where i run the main algorithm:

```
    def run(self):
        self.playing = True
        self.hunger()
        while self.playing:
            self.dt = self.clock.tick(FPS) / 1000
            self.events()
            self.draw()
            self.update()
```

and here's how i check for events(including keyboard commands)

```
    def events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.quit()
            if event.type == self.HUNGEREVENT:
                self.food_bar = self.food_bar - 10
                self.all_sprites.update()
                pygame.display.flip()

            if event.type == pygame.K_f:
                self.money_bar = self.money_bar - 10
                self.food_bar = self.food_bar + 15
                self.all_sprites.update()
                pygame.display.flip()

            if event.type == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                self.quit()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry for responding so late, but thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `pygame.K_f` is a key enumerator constant (see [`pygame.key`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html)) the content of `event.type` is event enumerator constant (see [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html)).
If you want to determine if a certain key is pressed, the you've to verify if the event type is `pygame.KEYDOWN` (or `pygame.KEYUP` for button release) and if the `.key` attribute of the event is equal the key enumerator. e.g.:

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        self.quit()

    # [...]

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_f:
            # [...]
```