# Pygame doesn't play mp3 files tagged with mutagen

Tags: python, pygame, tagging, mutagen

After tagging an audio file with `mutagen` pygame no longer seems to be able to play the file. It however loads the file successfully and the call to `pygame.mixer.music.play()` throws no error. I actually use the `music-tag` library which is just a wrapper around `mutagen` for tagging the files. Was wondering if this is known issue.

Code for tagging

```
import music_tag

f = music_tag.load_file('sample.mp3')
f['title'] = 'Smells like teen spirit'
f['artwork'] = open('nirvana.jpg', 'rb').read()
f.save()
```

Code for playback

```
from pygame import mixer
mixer.init()

mixer.music.load('sample.mp3') 

mixer.music.set_volume(0.7) 
mixer.music.play(-1) 

while True:
    query = input()
    if query == 'q':
        mixer.music.stop()
        break;
```

I've also noticed that on removal of the tags, pygame does play the file except the playback is really, really distorted and very different from the actual audio on the file. Meanwhile other mp3 players play the same file with or without tags just fine.

Comment: if I were you I wouldn't overwrite the same file that you have read. Try changing that first. Try also to play the tagged file with any mp3 player.

Comment: btw, the example [here](https://pypi.org/project/music-tag/) uses `with open(...`, which has the effect of closing again the image file – something that you don't do but should do

Comment: @WalterTross Thanks for the suggestions. Playing the tagged song with other mp3 players like `vlc` and `totem` works. And the problem doesn't seem to be how the file is opened. Also I don't understand what you mean by not overwriting the same file..

Comment: well, `f.save()` overwrites the same file that was read previously, I guess. In general this is a bad idea, although I noticed (after writing my comment) that the example in the doc does the same.

Comment: @WalterTross I have no idea how to go about not overwriting the same file

Comment: as usual, the documentation sucks. The line should be [this one](https://github.com/KristoforMaynard/music-tag/blob/262d90adf74faa032c26f2224054d80720490b91/music_tag/file.py#L370), so all you need to do is `f.save('tagged_sample.mp3')`. Please note also the comment on the next line...

Answer (score 0):

`input ()` blocks the entire application until an input is made. Use the `KEYDOWN` event to detect when <kbd>q</kbd> is pressed (see also [Problem when using keyboard commands in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58299480/problem-when-using-keyboard-commands-in-pygame/58307655#58307655)):

```py
from pygame import mixer
mixer.init()

mixer.music.load('sample.mp3') 
mixer.music.set_volume(0.7) 
mixer.music.play(-1) 

run = True
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                mixer.music.stop()
                run = False
```